# Making column into new row according to screen size, making website responsive

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I need to make my page responsive by shifting the last two columns as a new row. How do i implement that in javascript? Kindly give me the javascript snippet. Currently table is

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That should change to

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This should work not only with resizing the screen of the browser but also when opened on a mobile handheld device

Comment: How much do you pay? Also looks like you misuse table element. It is purposed to show tabular data, not to create layouts.

Comment: What about a responsive framework?  skelJS, bootstrap, foundation ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking this. Don't use `table` for the layout. Use `table` for tables.

For the website's grid, employ other, more suitable [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) like `div` or `section`. In your case  [floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) divs would be one way to go.

What you need can be achieved with [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and basic HTML structure. Don't use JavaScript if you don't actually need it.